# How to read a file of the EFI partition using gnu-efi

Tags: gnu, uefi, gnu-efi

I used gnu-efi.
I do not understand how to simply read file.
I understand about using the BlockIOProtocol.

Could you tell us along with a simple example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a simple example handy, sorry. But in general you proceed like this

- in `EfiMain` you have an `IMAGE_HANDLE` of your loaded image
- use `LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL` on the image handle to obtain an device handle of the device this image was loaded from (= the EFI partition)
- Use `SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL` on the device handle to call `OpenVolume`, which will give you a `EFI_FILE` of the filesystem root
- call `Open` on the root to open your file and `Read` on the resulting handle to read from it.
- Don't forget to release all your handles afterwards.

Hope this helps.